# EXCEL VBA UserInterfaceOnly:= True not working

Tags: excel, vba

When I use `(some code here).copy destination:=(some code there)`. It will still prompt for `protection issues on cells`. Basically it just won't let my code runs.

Comment: Same issue here. Mine can't even work in workbook_open for no reason :(

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The status `UserInterfaceOnly:=TRUE`is unfortunately not stored in the file - therefore, if you reopen the file, it will be fully protected. Either use the `Workbook_Open` event to reapply this protection status - or unprotect and then reprotect the worksheet in your VBA code directly.

See [Ozgrid](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/excel-macro-protected-sheet.htm) for further details!

Comment: Very lamentable. This means Excel (still in 2021) cannot have VBA operating on protected cells. You can use no password or expose the password in the VBA, but these workarounds somewhat diminish the concept of protection.

Comment: @DAG Agree. You can password protect your VBA code. Again, not perfect - will deter most users. Anyone really trying to break into your Excel file will succeed with enough persistence regardless of your measures - excel is simply not the right tool if you’re looking for highest data security.

Answer (score 0):

I posted one approach to solving this here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69730040/13307304

Like Peter Albert mentioned, the password itself should not be hardcoded