# Excel VBA protect returning error

Tags: vba, excel

I've seen many posts on here and elsewhere about using the following code in the `ThisWorkbook` Object in order to protect your workbook but still allow macros to run:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    ActiveWorkbook.Protect UserInterfaceOnly:=True
End Sub
```

However, the protect function tooltip that pops up only offers three arguments Protect([password], [structure], [windows]). Therefore, when I open the document I get the following error

> "Compile Error: Named argument not found"

in regard to `UserInterfaceOnly:=True`.

Am I using the wrong protect function, or is there something else I'm missing? I want to allow users to input data into the workbook using forms/macros, but I don't want them to be able to manually change any cells.

It almost seems as if the protect function that I'm running has different arguments than many of the other protect solutions I've found. Could this be a version issue or something else?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBA Excel: Sheet protection: UserInterFaceOnly gone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38353751/vba-excel-sheet-protection-userinterfaceonly-gone)

Comment: I'm asking something different. I already have the code in the `Workbook_Open`, however, VBA doesn't seem to be recognizing the `UserInterfaceOnly:=True` argument at all.

Comment: That argument is for worksheets, not the workbook.

Comment: Okay, so is the solution to repeat this code at `Workbook_Open` for each sheet I need protected?

Comment: Yes - that's correct.

Comment: @M.Terry: see [Peter Albert's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14162717/2107722)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The suggestion provided by [Tim Williams](https://stackoverflow.com/users/478884/tim-williams) worked. Protect doesn't work the same way at the workbook level, therefore I needed to write individual code for each sheet I wanted to protect. I used the following code to protect the sheets but allow forms to populate:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Protect UserInterfaceOnly:=True
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Protect UserInterfaceOnly:=True
    Worksheets("Sheet3").Protect UserInterfaceOnly:=True
End Sub
```