# Protect excel sheet with some exceptions

Tags: vba, excel

I have a excel sheet in which I am using macros, dropdowns and buttons. I have also got a lot of formulas in different cells like multiplication, vlookup etc. The buttons work in such a way that when I press it adds a empty row and adds some data to it. There are few cells in which the user is supposed to enter the data

Buttons, formulae and dropdowns change  and add new data to different cells

Now I want to protect the sheet so that the user can't change the content by mistake or intentionally.

But when I protect the sheet its shows error on using the sheet because buttons, multiplication and vlookup tend to change the data in different cells all the time.

Is it possible to make the sheet read only for the user (except for some cells where is supposed to enter the data) and  allow macros, formulae and dropdowns to change the cell content

Comment: If you can protect your sheet via code when the workbook opens, you can use the "user interface only" option to allow your VBA to still make updates. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/125449/how-to-protect-cells-in-excel-but-allow-these-to-be-modified-by-vba-script

Comment: I need more information. Are the dropdowns in Data Validation lists or Form/Active-X controls? Do you add buttons for every added row or are they static? Can you show the code behind the macros, buttons and dropdowns? Which version of Excel are you using? Do you need VBA to copy the formulae down from the row above when you add a row or are you using Excel tables that will do that for you automatically?

Comment: @Tim Williams Thanks for the link, it gave me exactly what I needed, 'Worksheets("conf").Protect Password:="", UserInterfaceOnly:=True' also enables changes in the cells by the formulae                                              I used "allow users to edit ranges" under the review tab of excel for the data validation

Comment: @Mark Fitzgerald Thanks for your concern but the problem is solved now

Answer (score 1):

place a macro in the workbook_open() to unlock your sheet first then at the end of your other macros place the lock macro ex:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
  On Error Resume Next
       Sheets("Sheet1").Unprotect Password:=""

  *****your codes here

       Sheets("Sheet1").Protect Password:=""
end sub
```

this will make sure your sheet is not locked when your codes run but will lock once your codes are done.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I used your code and it worked fine, but now I am using this                                                                                                                                         'Worksheets("conf").Protect Password:="", UserInterfaceOnly:=True'                                This way I don't need to add unprotect or protect  password with every macro