# Google Apps Script - Macro to edit contents of protected range

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm making a spreadsheet for users where I would like to have a specific range protected so they cannot be edited by users, but they can be edited by a macro that runs whenever the sheet is opened. I protected the range, but when users open the page it says they cannot edit the protected cells, as in the macro cannot edit the cells.

[I know this is possible with VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125449/how-to-protect-cells-in-excel-but-allow-these-to-be-modified-by-vba-script) but I was wondering if there's something similar for Google Apps Script.

Thanks

Comment: I have answered this on [this article](http://www.steegle.com/google-products/google-apps-script-faq#TOC-How-do-permissions-work-on-Apps-Script-) please take a look.

Comment: Ive removed the -1 as its a valid question and docs are not clear. henrique's article has the solution (instalable triggers)