# Prevent User to edit range of cells manual (but allowing VBA to do)

Tags: excel, vba, edit

I'd like to prevent the user from being able to editing a certain range of cells. But VBA should keep the ability to do this. So when a button in Excel is pressed VBA should be able make modifications in the Cell's values, while the user can't do this manually.

**Just found a sollution in an other toppic which rather fits my demands:** [How to protect cells in Excel but allow these to be modified by VBA script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125449/how-to-protect-cells-in-excel-but-allow-these-to-be-modified-by-vba-script?rq=1)

Only thing I'm still questioning is if this is alwso aplicable to a certain range instead of the whole workbook?

Comment: To prevent the user to modify the cell, protect them (and the worksheet). When you need to modify them with VBA, just unprotect them, do you modifications and re-protect them after.

Comment: Then I would end up protecting and unprotecting endles times, due my code contains a lot of parts where the user/VBA  take turns on editing the Workbook. thanks though!

Comment: No other choice, sorry. But you can make two Sub to protect and Unprotect the cells that you call at the start and at the end of your VBA processing.

Comment: Didn't remember of UserInterfaceOnly parameter, my bad.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to protect cells in Excel but allow these to be modified by VBA script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/125449/how-to-protect-cells-in-excel-but-allow-these-to-be-modified-by-vba-script)

Comment: yes... but would like to know how to apply this on just a certain range

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Sollution**

Worksheet.Protect "Password", UserInterfaceOnly := True

to Apply on a certain Range (I gues the folloing code should work...?):

```
Worksheet.Sheets("ControlSheet").Range("M5:N19").Protect "Password", UserInterfaceOnly :=True
```

Answer (score 1):

Protect the sheet with VBA:

```
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim myPassword As String
myPassword = "password"

For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    sh.Protect Password:=myPassword
Next sh
```

Now, if you want to modify something with VBA you can unprotect them with:

```
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim myPassword As String
myPassword = "password"

For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    sh.Unprotect Password:=myPassword
Next sh
```

And then protect them again afterwards.

Comment: p.s. bas de beer is een bazen spel

#90s