# VBA for Excel: Unlock cells in protected sheet, while allowing VBA to edit them

Tags: vba, excel

I have a protected sheet ("Exercise Selection") with all cells locked except two.

Let's assume the *only* unlocked cells are A1 and A2, which are merged.

What I want to do, is that when cell A1 and A2 has the value of "Plank (achieved)" (which you can write since it's unlocked), then cell B1 and B2 (which are also merged) will be unlocked. Now you have four cells unlocked. In case you write something besides "Plank (achieved)" in cells A1 and A2, the cells B1 and B2 will still be locked until you write it correctly and the macro is run.

Is there a way to make it? The macro is named "UnlockPushup". Note that in the title I wrote *while still allowing VBA to edit them* because the new unlocked cells will be locked if the value of "Plank (achieved)" is changed.

I have this macro, but I haven't tested it and I think it won't work. Any `enter code here`ideas?

```
    Sub UnlockPushup
       If Worksheets("Exercise Selection").Range("A1:A2").Value >= "Plank (achieved)" Then
             ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="hardestpassword"
             Worksheets("Exercise Selection").Range("B1:B2").Locked = False
             ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="hardestpassword"
          Else
             ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="hardestpassword"
             Worksheets("Exercise Selection").Range("B1:B2").Locked = True
             ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="hardestpassword"
       End If
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

See the solution in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125449/how-to-protect-cells-in-excel-but-allow-these-to-be-modified-by-vba-script), you can add **UserInterfaceOnly** to the Protect method, so it allows VBA to change values without unprotecting.

To make the solution work, you need to change all the code that calls `.Protect` method to have the parameter **`UserInterfaceOnly:=True`**

e.g.
`Activesheet.Protect "hardestpassword", UserInterfaceOnly:=True`

Once the worksheet is protected with this param, cells value can be changed within VBA macro without calling **`.Unprotect`**.

Comment: Thanks. And how about the macro?

Comment: @alej27 You may need to do lots of changes to your existing macro that calls the `.Protect`. You may be better off to create a separate generic **Sub** to Protect worksheets. e.g. pass worksheeet name into that Sub.