# howto refresh all sheets after protect sheet in excel

Tags: excel, vba

My excel file have 2 sheets
with named "A" and "B"

Both sheets showed the data from 6 queries (6 connection name) with view of sql server

Ordinary when I want to update the data in excel file,
I press "refresh all"

but when I protect sheet
"refresh all" can't process

How Do I refresh all sheets including those with protection.

Answer (score 1):

check out this solution

How to protect cells in Excel but allow these to be modified by VBA script

https://stackoverflow.com/a/126032/6868389

Answer (score 0):

my code is work if time for "refresh all" is a short time

but for my case 
"refresh all" take time about 15 minutes

and "protect sheet" process is begin to process before "refresh all" process has done

[image]