# VBA: how to change DataLabel NumberFormat when Protected

Tags: vba, format, label, protected, trendline

I am adding a Trendline to a Chart and want to change the NumberFormat in the datalabel before I capture the datalabel as a string. Originally I was doing it like this:

```
Sub AddLine()
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Trendlines.Add Type:=xlLinear, _
        intercept:=0, DisplayEquation:=1, DisplayRSquared:=1, Name:="Linear"
End Sub
Sub Eqn()
    Dim t As Trendline
    Dim eqn As String
    Set t = ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Trendlines(1)
    t.DataLabel.NumberFormat = "0.0000E+00"
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
    eqn = ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Trendlines(1).DataLabel.text
    'other stuff
End Sub
Sub Run()
    Call AddLine
    Call Eqn
End Sub
```

This was working fine until I started protecting my sheets. I specifically protected my sheets in VBA so I could use UserInterFaceOnly:=True. Despite this, VBA is throwing an error when I try to change the NumberFormat. I tried to get around this by changing my code to the following:

```
Sub AddLine()
    With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1)
        .Trendlines.Add Type:=xlExponential, Forward:=0, Backward:=0, _
            DisplayEquation:=1, DisplayRSquared:=1, Name:="Exponential"
        .Trendlines(1).DataLabel.NumberFormat = "0.0000E+00"
    End With
End Sub
Sub Eqn()
    Dim eqn As String
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
    eqn = ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Trendlines(1).DataLabel.text
    'other stuff
End Sub
Sub Run()
    Call AddLine
    Call Eqn
End Sub
```

This also worked just fine when it was operating without protection, but again threw an error when I got to setting the NumberFormat when it was protected.

Is there a way to change the NumberFormat of a Trendline.DataLabel when the worksheet is protected with UserInterFaceOnly:=True?

Comment: Unprotect the sheet, do the change, re-protect the sheet.

Comment: Shouldn't there be a more precise way to do it?

Comment: I don't understand what "precise" means in this context. The sheet is protected, a user can't modify it - code can't modify it either, that's what it's being protected for.

Comment: Actually, there is: https://stackoverflow.com/a/126032/1188513 - if *that* doesn't work, then you're out of options.

Comment: I've already set the protect to UserInterfaceOnly. That's how I'm able to run my VBA at all. For some reason when my trendline is being added it's protected from the vba.

Comment: So, I guess that leaves one option then!